# Parsing an empty string with Gson returns null instead of throwing JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, gson

In order to have `Gson` throw an exception when it tries to deserialize an empty `String`, [this comment](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/457#issuecomment-83705909) suggests doing

```
gson.getAdapter(Foo.class).fromJson("")
```

instead of

```
gson.fromJson("", Foo.class)
```

The problem I'm having is that does not work when the `gson` in question has a custom adapter registered. Can anyone suggest a different workaround to get this unit test to pass:

```
@Test
public void testEmptyStringBehavior() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Foo.class, new JsonDeserializer<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public Foo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Never gets here");
        }
    }).create();
    try {
        gson.getAdapter(Foo.class).fromJson("");
        fail("Expected JsonSyntaxException");
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException | IOException e) {
        // Expected.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use `jackson`, instead of using `Gson`, it is very easy.

```
package parse;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "";

        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

here i am using empty jsonString, by which it is throwing exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really answer my question. For starters, I am using Gson on a large code base--can't just switch out to Jackson. Second, your example doesn't deserialize to a `Foo` object, but to a `JsonNode`.